# How to make zsh run executable script file with zsh by default?

Tags: shell, command, sh, zsh

After I switched from `bash` to `zsh`, one thing is bothering me while running executable scripts.

When I used `bash`, if I run some script like:

```
./test.sh
```

`bash` will run this script with `bash`

But if I do the same thing in `zsh`, it will run that with `sh`.
Is it possible to change this default behavior of `zsh`?

Maybe using `#!` is a solution but I'm trying to find another method fixing that by just setting once.

Comment: The shebang line controls what program is used to run an executable text file.

Comment: Each script should have a shebang line indicating what language/dialect it's written in. If it's  a shell script and uses bash extensions, it should have a bash shebang (either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`). If it's written using standard/portable shell syntax, `#!/bin/sh` is appropriate. If it's a perl, python, ruby, awk, etc script, it should have an appropriate shebang for that language.

Comment: There's an extensive discussion of how various shells react to a script without a `#!` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/432774). TL;DR: POSIX is  ambiguous about what should happen. There does not appear to be a way to change the default behavior in any shell, and adding hashbangs is probably the only consistent method to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is provided by @Gairfowl: POSIX is ambiguous about what should happen. There does not appear to be a way to change the default behavior in any shell, and adding hashbangs is probably the only consistent method to get the behavior you want.